# How did the police get the same mask and vest as the thieves in Money Heist?

Tags: plot-explanation, money-heist

In S01E06 of *Money Heist*, we see that 2 policemen are trying to infiltrate the bank and blend with the hostages by wearing the same mask and vests (although they withdrew when they knew what happened afterwards).

How did the policemen get those same masks and vests as the thieves? The masks are a specialty of the robbers in the show and so only they have them. In other words, the masks are the property of the thieves. They appeared in the public as a team for the 1st time wearing those marks so they were neither stolen from them nor got misplaced. So, how did the policeman manage to get those unique masks?

Similar question: [In the tv show Money Heist, what was the impact of changing masks?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106187/in-the-tv-show-money-heist-what-was-the-impact-of-changing-masks)

Comment: Do you seriously think that it was hard for the police to make copies of these masks? At this point they must have had hundreds of photos and videos of the thieves wearing them and they knew it's a face of Salvador Dali. Note that they didn't have to be 100% identical in every detail, very similar masks would be enough to blend in.

Comment: It take around 24 hours for someone on internet to recreate a prop shown in movie trailer. I think same person could do it with the amount of photos and references for the police. Source - Adam Savage 24 hours builds

Comment: Do they claim in the show that the Dali mask were not common items from a costume shop? In-universe, it makes sense to use common items, so that the robbers cannot be linked to a precise supplier.

Comment: so if going by your statement, even the common people were having that type of mask while they were protesting in front of bank of spain. So how could they get it ? its not that too tough I guess